# vscodium actions.find cannot find filename without absolute path

Tags: vscodium

I was using ATOM as IDE now I've been forced to turn to vscode/vscodium.

CTRL+F seems to be inherited but actions.find seems to work only if entire absolute path is passed as search term, is there a way to allow a relative search from current workspace folder to subdirectory?

Searching for:

```
/root/directory/currentdirectory/sub/templatename.html
```

goes successfully, instead if i insert only:

```
partoftemplatename
```

result in nothing found.

How can I get `currentdirectory/sub/templatename.html` as result, in  other words how can I enable action.find to search partials patterns ?